# Pointers to Pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

Ok I understand the concept of pointers to pointers. But I don't know why this doesn't work.

```
void function(int **x) 
{
    *x = 10;
}
```

I keep getting the error: 
a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int*"

What am I doing wrong or what am I not understanding about pointers to pointers?

omg x_x I was confusing C with C++.

Comment: When you said `I understand the concept of pointers to pointers`, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign the value `10` to a pointer?  What's at the tenth address in memory that's so fascinating?

Comment: @MooingDuck that elusive tenth address. I think it contains the keys to google!

Comment: @MooingDuck Perhaps the idea is to find out.

Comment: The question is _how did you expect it to work?_

Comment: It's obviously missing a cast since `10` is of type `int` and not of type `int*`:  `*x = static_cast<int*>(10);` Of course the usefulness of doing this (instead of say `**x = 10` to assign to the contained integer) might be debatable.

Comment: @Grizzly: Such a cast is not allowed with `static_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` allows it.

Answer (score 10):

x is a pointer to a pointer so you have to dereference it twice to get to the actual object. E.g. `**x = 10;`

Answer (score 7):

> Ok I understand the concept of pointers to pointers.

Nah...

`*x` is an `int*`, so you can't assign an `int` to it.

The concept of pointers-to-pointers comes from C, where references aren't available. It allows reference semantics - i.e. you can change the original pointer.

Comment: You _can_ assign an `int` to a pointer, integers are convertible into pointers. 99.999% of the time, you shouldn't, of course.

Comment: Yea I was looking into pointers-to-pointers on the internet and ran into some C examples. I thought they were interchangeable.

Comment: @DanielFischer is the cast implicit? (that's what I mean). And AFAIK, you can assign anything to anything :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore In C (which the question originally was tagged as), most compilers will warn but compile without cast (I'm not sure whether they'd be allowed to reject the program without cast). In C++, you need an explicit cast of course.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore no, the cast is not implicit (you get a compiler warning). And that 'everything to everything' is not fully true - try to assign two structs of different type.

Comment: @H2CO3 http://ideone.com/N6dOH I know it's incorrect & ugly, but the point is it's allowed...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore No, empty structs aren't allowed by the standard, they're a gcc extension.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore of course. And there's `struct A one = *(struct A *)&two;` but anyways...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore OK so then I paraphrase: try to assign an integer to a struct.

Comment: @DanielFischer 1. Really? 2. Even if not empty, that code is valid.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore 1. I thought you were talking about C, I'm not sure about C++, sorry. 2. may be, it wouldn't be valid C, though, you'd have to take the address and cast the pointer, then dereference it, to do that in C.

Answer (score 6):

In short, you need to dereference twice. 
A dereference returns the thing a pointer is ponting to, so:

```
int   n     = 10;   //here's an int called n
int*  pInt  = &n;   //pInt points to n (an int)
int** ppInt = &pInt //ppInt points to pInt (a pointer)

cout << ppInt;      //the memory address of the pointer pInt (since ppInt is pointing to it)
cout << *ppInt;     //the content of what ppInt is pointing to (another memory address, since ppInt is pointing to another pointer
cout << *pInt;      //the content of what pInt is pointing to (10)
cout << **ppInt;    //the content of what the content of ppInt is pointing to (10)
```

Answer (score 0):

x is pointing to a type of `int *`, not `int`. You either want to do `static int i = 10; *x = &i` or `**x = 10`.

Comment: You cannot take the address of a constant like that.

Comment: Certainly not `&10`. Constants have no address.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, in this case you're right, but it would be OK if it were `const int`.

Comment: @MarkRansom no, it would not be OK. I think you need to take a pointer primer, mate :)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, A quick test shows you're right again. I was positive that I had done this in the past - certainly there's nothing to prevent the compiler from putting the constant in memory to take the address of it.

Comment: @MarkRansom there is. The thing is that constants are also just constants in the resulting assembly/machine code. They're hardcoded. They're not in the RAM.

Comment: @H2CO3, I don't see how that follows. String literals are in RAM, aren't they? Why should integer literals be different unless they're optimized out? (Of course I know the answer, it's because the language defines it to be so, but it wasn't intuitive to me)

Comment: @MarkRansom because integer literals are not arrays. Strings are.